# Missing 'pi'-Symbol from euler font in sans serif?

Tags: math-mode, sans-serif

I want to set one formula in my document in a sans serif font. As a math font I use the `eulervm`-Package. Unfortunately, the `\pi` is missing (instead a small line appears).

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage{eulervm} 
\begin{document} 
\pagestyle{empty}

$2\cdot\pi$ 

$\mathsf{2\cdot\pi}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above givn example]

It makes no difference, whether I take pdflatex or latex. When I remove the `fontenc` package, the problem is still there, but then I get a `\beta`-symbol instead of the desired `\pi`.

Is there a workaround or something I do not understand here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `\mathsf` in this way. This is not a command to change the font setup of a complete formula. You should only use it to get some sans serif characters (mostly letters). E.g. `\mathsf{A}`.

To change the whole font setup of a formula one must define a so-called mathversion (as an example see `\mathversion{bold}`. To be able to do it you need suitable fonts for all the symbols (letters, operators, etc).

If you need only a few sans serif symbols you need at least fonts which contains this symbols.

Side remark: In normal text features like "bold", "sans serif" and "italic" are used for emphasis. They don't change the meaning of the text. This is different in math. There a sans serif "A" can mean a very different object than an italic "A". So by very careful when changing the font setup.

Comment: Thanks for the hint to `\mathversion`. I did not know that. But when I get your answer correctly, the euler font does not contain a sans-serif pi, which is very unfortunate.

Comment: Well euler doesn't contain sans-serif letter either it uses the letters from the text sans serif. If you load e.g. `\usepackage{helvet}` **before** eulervm you can see that `\mathsf` uses the letters from arial.

Comment: Thanks again! I am using the helvet-package, but -stupid me- I did load it after eulervm. There are some greek letters still missing. For now I use the `\uppi` fom the upgreek-package, but I have to look further or change the math-font away from euler.